# Track an email via Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create I don't have any idea how can I create that, need your help guys. What I am doing is I have created a google spreadsheet to send emails. Now I am trying to add script to check Number of Opened Email, Number of Clicked from that email, No of Bounced or Invalid Emails.

Is it possible to do that in Google scripts?

**Please guide me related to this.**
**If you guys think that this is not the place to post please let me know.**

If I wanted to implement below is how it should look

```
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
+       Schedule       +    Email      +    Subject  +    Message            +    Bounced  +    Click  +    Open  +
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
+ 04/22/2015 18:00:00  + abc@abc_17.com+      Hi     + email template content+       1     +      0    +      0   +
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
+ 04/25/2015 14:00:00  + def@gmail.com +      Hi     + email template content+       0     +      1    +      1   +
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: You want to go through your inbox and count the number of emails with `x` status? Or do you want to see if an email that was sent has been opened? What do you mean by `Number of Clicked from that email` ?

Comment: show us what you tried so far. each is done in many possible ways.

Comment: The volume of the emails will affect the possible solutions to this. If it is a lot then email quotas will imply sending via a group mailing list which has far fewer options available. If it really isn't so many my favourite GAS integration is with the Url Shortener API.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell  I want to see if an email that was sent has been opened. I am sending email via Google Spreadsheet using google script. In that email I have added Links and Images. If Person opens that email then my spreadsheet should get populated with it. Same for bounced email which contains either email is under span or email address which was sent is not valid.

Comment: @Jonathon what is GAS integration?

Comment: Google Apps Script = GAS.

Comment: @Jonathon I am already using GAS to send emails. Now I wanted to implement things which I have mentioned in my post description

Comment: I think this depends whether the mail service provider gives you an rsvp kinda thing (confirmation that an email has been opened). I don't think Gmail does that.

Comment: @manu29.d I don't think you know that technology. There is a way I don't know either how to program it.  But one of the way to do it is via Google Analytics. But how to populate even I have a question.